# Azure Point to Site VPN with Basic SKU not working on Windows 10 (ErrorCode = 720 ErrorSource = RAS)

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I am trying to connect to Azure vNET Gateway and I am not having success. It ends with ErrorCode = 720 ErrorSource = RAS. Anyone experienced this issue before for the following scenario?

- Azure vNET Gateway configured with Basic SKU.
- VpnStrategy is SSTP for Windows 10
- Authentication: Client certificate (self signed)
- Both the root and client certificates are in current user personal store. They are resolved ok.
- Root cert is stored in trusted root path of current user
- Root cert is saved in Azure vpn gateway user configuration without line breaks
- Don't wish to create other SKU to save $$ on poc
- Deleted all the WAN Miniport adapters and rebooted the machine with no success. They get recreated automatically
- I can't share certificates (root or client) in this forum since I am revealing the vpn gateway endpoint in the logs (for security reason)

Event logs from local machine in the order of execution:

```
CoId={3285D778-432A-4746-B74C-8B95FECEB53E}: The user SYSTEM has started dialing a Connection Manager connection using a per-user connection profile named az-aks-vnet-v2. The connection settings are: 
Dial-in User = P2SDemoClientCert
VpnStrategy = SSTP
DataEncryption = Require
PrerequisiteEntry = 
AutoLogon = No
UseRasCredentials = Yes
Authentication Type = EAP <Microsoft: Smart Card or other certificate>
Ipv4DefaultGateway = No
Ipv4AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv4DNSServerAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DefaultGateway = Yes
Ipv6AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DNSServerAssignment = By Server
IpDnsFlags = 
IpNBTEnabled = Yes
UseFlags = Private Connection
ConnectOnWinlogon = No.

CoId={3285D778-432A-4746-B74C-8B95FECEB53E}: The user SYSTEM is trying to establish a link to the Remote Access Server for the connection named az-aks-vnet-v2 using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = azuregateway-b80c0077-e69d-4f0c-8f50-baa0c7a6e23e-0fe0aceeddbb.vpn.azure.com
Device = WAN Miniport (SSTP)
Port = VPN1-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={3285D778-432A-4746-B74C-8B95FECEB53E}: The user SYSTEM has successfully established a link to the Remote Access Server using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = azuregateway-b80c0077-e69d-4f0c-8f50-baa0c7a6e23e-0fe0aceeddbb.vpn.azure.com
Device = WAN Miniport (SSTP)
Port = VPN1-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={3285D778-432A-4746-B74C-8B95FECEB53E}: The link to the Remote Access Server has been established by user SYSTEM.

CoId={3285D778-432A-4746-B74C-8B95FECEB53E}: The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named az-aks-vnet-v2 which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 720.
```

VPN logs:

```
******************************************************************
    Operating System      : Windows NT 10.0 
    Dialer Version        : 7.2.18362.1
    Connection Name       : az-aks-vnet-v2
    All Users/Single User : Single User
    Start Date/Time       : 6/22/2020, 10:31:31
******************************************************************
    Module Name, Time, Log ID, Log Item Name, Other Info
    For Connection Type, 0=dial-up, 1=VPN, 2=VPN over dial-up
******************************************************************
[cmdial32]  10:31:31    03  Pre-Init Event  CallingProcess = C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasautou.exe
[cmdial32]  10:31:40    04  Pre-Connect Event   ConnectionType = 1
[cmdial32]  10:31:40    06  Pre-Tunnel Event    UserName = P2SDemoClientCert Domain =  DUNSetting = b80c0077-e69d-4f0c-8f50-baa0c7a6e23e Tunnel DeviceName =  TunnelAddress = azuregateway-b80c0077-e69d-4f0c-8f50-baa0c7a6e23e-0fe0aceeddbb.vpn.azure.com
[cmdial32]  10:31:42    21  On-Error Event  ErrorCode = 720 ErrorSource = RAS
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is resolved, I just needed a break from computer and take a long evening walk! This is what I did to fix the problem-

- Open Device Manager
- Go to Network Adapters
- Uninstall all the adapters name starts with "WAN Miniport". Repeat the step for every “WAN Miniport driver” installed
- **I didn't reboot the machine.**
- Right click “Network adapters” and select “Scan for hardware changes”
- All of the WAN Miniport adapters will reappear immediately

I was able to connect to the VPN Gateway after the above steps and connect to VM with private ip.

Thanks to [svenvdveen](https://svenvdveen.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/azure-p2s-vpn-connection-problems-error-720/#:%7E:text=When%20setting%20up%20a%20P2S,network%20settings%20for%20this%20connection.&text=Create%20your%20VPN%20connection%20like%20you%20normally%20should.) for the solution with the exception of no reboot. I followed the same instruction (twice) before and I rebooted the machine but didn't have luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with Azure Basic Gateway.

For anyone reading this, I suggest you start by simply uninstalling the Wan Miniport (Ikev2). Then try to connect to your VPN again. It worked in my case :).

(Windows 11)